# How to prevent google Gtag to do not fire multiple times on ReactJS route change?

Tags: reactjs, gtag.js

When I change route path gtag.js fires multiple times instead of one.

```
componentDidMount() {
const { editor, gtag } = this.props;
if (!editor) {
  ReactPixel.pageView();
  ReactPixel.track('abc');
  gtag.event("conversion", {
    'send_to': 'II-123123/AbC12a3B'
  });

}
```

}

Comment: Where does the component that has this `componentDidMount` method lives in your app?

Comment: It is a form with 5 steps and when I change from step one to two it fires multiple gtags.

Comment: I wanted to see the code for the file that containes this one, can you include in the question please?